# Can we nest two OptionMenu widgets in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, nested

Just like the famous example of having Continent names in one dropdown and display country names related to selected Continent. How to achieve this using Tkinter? 
I have Continent list in first dropdown and list of all countries related to continents in the list. I would like to display country_11,country_12 when continent_1 is selected, similarly for other continents.

Here is the piece of code am working on -

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
#Label to Continent 
label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Select the Continent", font = (8), bg = '#ffe1c4')
label_1.place(x = 120, y = 220)

# Continent selection - drop down
optionList1 = ["Continent1", "Continent2","Continent3"]
dropVar1 = StringVar()
dropMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropVar1 , *optionList1)
dropMenu1.place(x = 300, y = 220)

#Label to Select Country 
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Select the Country ", font = (8), bg = '#ffe1c4')
label_2.place(x = 120, y = 250)

# Country  name selection - drop down
optionList2 = ["Country_11", "Country_12", "Country_21","Country_22","Country_31","Country_32"]
dropVar2 = StringVar()
dropMenu2 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropVar2, *optionList2)
dropMenu2.place(x = 300, y = 250)

root.mainloop()
```

Would be great to have a solution to this as am not aware of all the attributes OptionMenu can have in Tkinter.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mean is to create two `OptionMenu` and it will show the different value when select different value in the first dropdown menu.
You can try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

def func(selected_value): # the selected_value is the value you selected in the first drop down menu.
    dropMenu2.set_menu(*optionList2.get(selected_value))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
#Label to Continent
label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Select the Continent", font = (8), bg = '#ffe1c4')
label_1.place(x = 120, y = 220)

# Continent selection - drop down
optionList1 = ["-","Continent1", "Continent2","Continent3"]
dropVar1 = StringVar()
dropMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropVar1 , *optionList1,command=func) # bind a command for the first dropmenu
dropMenu1.place(x = 300, y = 220)

#Label to Select Country
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Select the Country ", font = (8), bg = '#ffe1c4')
label_2.place(x = 120, y = 250)

# Country  name selection - drop down
optionList2 = { # when select different value,show the list.
    "Continent1": ["Country_11", "Country_12"],
    "Continent2": ["Country_21", "Country_22"],
    "Continent3": ["Country_31", "Country_32"]
}
dropVar2 = StringVar()
dropMenu2 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropVar2, "-")
dropMenu2.place(x = 300, y = 250)

root.mainloop()
```

Now it is:
[image]

When select another value:
[image]

(A suggestion:`ttk.Combobox` is prettier than `OptionMenu`,and using `from tkinter import *` is not a good practice.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean menu inside a menu then it is possible and very simple to do because the menu used in `OptionMenu()` is a tkinter `Menu()`, See the [documentation of tkinter Menu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#menu.Menu.add-method).

We can access the `Menu` like so

```py
Op = OptionMenu(root, var, 'Hello', 'HI', 'YOO')

# Op_Menu is the Menu() class used for OptionMenu
Op_Menu = Op['menu']
```

---

Here is a small example of nested menus in an option menu. When you select any of the countries inside any continent the text of optionmenu won't change so to fix that I used `command` argument and in each command argument of country I'm changing the value of the `StringVar` that is assigned to the optionmenu.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
svar = tk.StringVar()
svar.set('Antarctica')

Op = tk.OptionMenu(root, svar, svar.get())
OpMenu = Op['menu']
Op.pack()

Menu1 = tk.Menu(OpMenu)
OpMenu.add_cascade(label='Africa', menu= Menu1)
Menu1.add_command(label='Algeria', command=lambda: svar.set('Africa - Algeria'))
Menu1.add_command(label='Benin', command=lambda: svar.set('Africa - Benin'))

Menu2 = tk.Menu(Op['menu'])
OpMenu.add_cascade(label='Asia', menu= Menu2)
Menu2.add_command(label='China', command=lambda: svar.set('Asia - China'))
Menu2.add_command(label='India', command=lambda: svar.set('Asia - India'))

root.mainloop()
```

Hope you find this helpful.